# Why doesn't basename execute in find?

Tags: shell, unix

```
find -name "*.c" -exec echo $(basename {}) \;
```

`basename` appears to do nothing. It just returns the whole path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$(basename {})` is evaluated before `find` is even started: you tell the shell to use the result of `basename {}` to construct `find` command line. So basically it does:

1. `$(basename {})` evaluates to `{}`
2. Calls `find -name "*.c" -exec echo {} \;`
3. `find` constructs all `-exec` commands; eg. `echo /path/to/file`

That's why you have only the whole path.

To achieve what you want, here is an example:

```
find . -name "*.c" -exec basename {} \;
```

Note that I added the starting path to `find`, otherwise it's not portable.

**UPDATE**: This answer shows an example from @chepner in a comment below. My previous example was way too complicated for no reason.

Comment: You don't need `xargs`; just run `basename` directly without the `echo`: `find . -name "*.c" -exec basename {} \;`.

Comment: Yes, you are totally right, I have no idea why I wanted such a complex line :-)

Answer (score 2):

[Jean-Sébastien Pédron's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36225200/45375):

- explains the problem with your solution attempt well.
- contains the best POSIX-compliant solution.

To complement it with the **most efficient solution**:

Use `-exec ... +` so as to pass as many matching paths as will fit on a single command line *at once*, typically only resulting in a *single* invocation of the utility specified:

```
find . -name "*.c" -exec basename -a {} +
```

Note that while `basename -a`, which allows *multiple* filenames to be passed, is not POSIX-compliant, it is is supported on Linux as well as on BSD/OSX.